# Error in appending to Bytes buffer in for loop and does not concat the entire array [Nodejs]

Tags: node.js, for-loop

I am trying to read files in a directory, for each file I am converting it into bytes array and appending everything in combinedBuffer array. Now I want to add all bytes buffer in combinedBuffer to finalBuffer, But I am not able to achieve this, it just iterate over the first bytes buffer in combinedBuffer rather than iterating over the entire combinedBuffer Array.

```
fileRead = async function(file){

    const testFolder = './items/';
    var dirFiles = [] // dirFiles Array
    fs.readdirSync(testFolder).forEach(file => {
      dirFiles.push(file)
    }) 
    dirFiles.sort(compareBasedonInt) //Natural Compare is to sort files in sampleFile1, SampleFile2.
    var combinedBuffer = []
    dirFiles.forEach(function(file){
       var eachfileBuffer= fs.readFileSync('./items/'+file) //eachfileBuffer is the bytes buffer which we get after reading the file
       combinedBuffer.push(eachfileBuffer)
    })
    var finalbuffer = Buffer.concat(combinedBuffer)
    console.log("final buffer", finalbuffer) // finalBuffer shows just first element of combinedBuffer
    console.log("combinedBuffer", combinedBuffer) // shows the array of all the bytes buffer
  }
```

Output

```
combinedBuffer [ <Buffer 2f 51 40 42 0b 0a 53 0c 4a 25 05 55 7f 06 32 79 0d 50 47 0c 5d 3e 59 0b 51 54 40 5c 4a 5e 53 4f 15 05 4d 1f 41 4e 23 07 1f 52 5f 1f 52 48 14 52 4e 52 ... >,
  <Buffer 19 42 01 0d 46 59 4a 58 1a 38 60 06 4a 11 2d 5c 70 65 2e 5a 17 0f 54 14 09 2a 05 14 38 34 47 0f 0e 42 5f 26 56 49 07 19 12 11 5e 4e 01 55 0b 41 26 72 ... >,
  <Buffer 17 1a 11 5d 4d 19 1e 44 45 45 57 5f 05 49 19 1a 18 2a 23 27 46 00 47 45 17 45 1c 4f 5b 4f 4b 53 45 55 3e 4b 1d 08 4b 15 1a 1c 18 66 50 1a 4f 55 18 05 ... >,
  <Buffer 44 0a 06 50 16 10 58 1b 15 40 07 22 58 0b 51 4e 08 07 46 6f 7c 66 12 57 4e 1d 1b 09 04 4a 40 4f 1e 11 5f 41 41 74 62 5f 76 43 5e 0d 1a 01 1a 0c 7d 44 ... >,
  <Buffer 3c 09 5f 5c 6c 15 5c 02 15 5d 00 40 03 09 46 54 49 16 5c 5a ff 9f a2 45 43 00 46 46 65 1b 11 5c 5d 54 29 46 44 07 02 14 45 4b 31 6a 3a 4d 0a 58 18 47 ... >,
  <Buffer 6d 4a 19 1b 85 bd ec 0c 0f 0f 4c 4a 41 08 09 1b 4f 0b 0a 1d 41 11 53 4b 1e 41 49 1e ce aa ad 11 22 1d 0f 52 46 1b 7a 0b 0e 15 1e 41 53 02 10 19 4f 01 ... >,
  <Buffer 03 58 69 48 04 5f 52 02 08 56 1f 07 76 4e 1d 53 12 5e 5e 58 47 0a 5a 44 77 06 16 5e 03 4a 4d 56 56 01 1f 0b 0c 0c 40 45 0e 0c 4e 08 1b 12 1a 45 4e 50 ... >,
  <Buffer 4d 5c 0c 4e 1d c2 a2 f9 1b 11 16 5f 52 00 0c 02 54 40 4d 17 0d 58 4c 1b 24 5b 12 41 4b 47 1a 0a 43 50 7c 6d 34 46 42 5a 43 42 43 38 1b 4b 53 57 5f 43 ... >,
  <Buffer 49 4e 1a 13 1c 19 0b 0a 5d 19 41 46 06 14 15 51 15 15 56 57 1c 5d 09 1e 00 41 4a 6f 13 0a 60 60 64 16 4c 01 1e 49 46 0e 50 1d 51 56 5c 09 0e 37 16 12 ... >,
  <Buffer 58 1d 4f 5b 4c 33 09 4f 08 19 04 1b 69 7e 2d 5d 22 95 be 8b 14 1b 76 4b 07 21 1f 4f 05 4b 30 2e 02 57 07 00 4d 5f 45 1c 08 39 37 37 41 47 25 09 05 4d ... >,
  <Buffer 58 42 43 1f 5e 1e 01 17 54 04 52 1c 1a 04 42 48 52 48 3e 03 05 12 4c 16 5a 49 7e 14 49 53 1a 6f 6f 2f 46 54 54 07 00 7a 23 0a 1c 3b 56 0f 73 0a 00 0b ... >]


finalbuffer <Buffer 2f 51 40 42 0b 0a 53 0c 4a 25 05 55 7f 06 32 79 0d 50 47 0c 5d 3e 59 0b 51 54 40 5c 4a 5e 53 4f 15 05 4d 1f 41 4e 23 07 1f 52 5f 1f 52 48 14 52 4e 52 ... >
```

Comment: Can you produce evidence of this output? As far as I can tell, the code there should work exactly as you described for the desired outcome. The only thing that seems off is that nothing in the function is `async`, but whatever you return from the function will be implicitly wrapped in a promise anyway.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I have edited the question and printed the CombinedBuffer and finalbuffer

Comment: The `...` is just the console truncating the Buffer for brevity. Check its length and you'll see it matches the length of all the previous buffers added together.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks much appreciated, i was taking it as that it is just reading the first iteration and not any of the subsequent ones.